# TimerTask behaving like running twice or more

Tags: java, android, timertask

I am trying to make a multiplayer (2 people) turn based game which lets users do whatever they want in 60 seconds. Added `Timer` and `TimerTask` to my project. When playing first time all is good, but when I return to main screen (previous intent) with something like exit game button and re-enter game counter seems to be running like twice. Instead of going like 60-59-58 it goes like 60-58-55-53 and so on. Should I do something to stop counter while exiting game?

Here is my code:

```
public class ikinciekren extends AppCompatActivity{

    ....

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        ...
        ...
        cikisonay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                kullanici.status(mDatabase,"lose");
                Intent intocan = new Intent(ikinciekren.this, MainActivity.class);
                intocan.putExtra("firebaseuser", facebookname);
                intocan.putExtra("firebaseuid", myuid);
                if(runstatus){
                    myTimer.cancel();
                    myTimer.purge();
                }
                startActivity(intocan);
            }
        });
        cikisiptal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        ...
        ...
        // On button click opponents timer starts to run
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                String number2 = number.getText().toString();
                if(number2!=null ||number2!=""){
                    if (number2.length()==4) {
                        status =false;
                        resetSomeTimer();
                        launchSomeTimer();
                        ...
                        ...
                    }
                }
            }


        });
        ...
        ...
        ValueEventListener postListener2 = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot != null && dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                    String turn = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue());
                    //Read a node in firebase database and acts according to that
                    if ("true".equals(turn)) {
                        status =true;
                    }                        
                    if ("false".equals(turn)) {
                        status =false;
                    }
                    resetSomeTimer();
                    launchSomeTimer();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to load post.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
        ...
        ...
    }
    protected void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        ///// added this just incase 
        if(runstatus){
            myTimer.cancel();
            myTimer.purge();
        }
        kullanici.status(mDatabase,"off");
        finish();
    }
    public void cikis(View view) {
        if(view.getId()==R.id.button3){
            ...
            ...
            cikisonay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ...
                    ...
                    ...
                    ///// added this just incase 
                    if(runstatus){
                        myTimer.cancel();
                        myTimer.purge();
                    }
                    startActivity(intocan);
                }
            });
            cikisiptal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            ...
        }
    }
    private void launchSomeTimer() {
        runstatus=true;
        oppenenttimertext.setText("60");
        owntimertext.setText("60");
        sayac =60;
        counter = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run () {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run () {
                        sayac--;
                        if (status) {
                            owntimertext.setText(String.valueOf(sayac));
                        } else {
                            oppenenttimertext.setText(String.valueOf(sayac));
                        }
                        if (sayac == 0) {
                            myTimer.cancel();
                            kullanici.timenotice(mDatabase);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.schedule(counter,1000,1000);

    }
    public void resetSomeTimer(){
        if(runstatus){
            myTimer.cancel();
            myTimer.purge();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try removing the finish() call from your onDestroy() method, and also calling super.onDestroy() last not first.  If this works, let me know and I'll put an official answer in.  Thanks!  If it doesn't work... try using print debugging.

Comment: @BooberBunz sorry mate, it didnt work.

Comment: Well basically you want to make sure that you remove each timer that you create.  This can be figured out with print debugging:  Log.i(TAG, "timer created in methodName()") // Log.i(TAG, "timer removed in methodName()").  If you see "created, created, removed, created, created" ... then you will know you are creating too many and one of your remove funtions is not being called for some reason... etc.

Comment: @BooberBunz , i added logs as you adviced and find out the launchsometimer() in valuevent listener starts to run twice for the same value when i leave the intent and reenter again, i dont know why.

Comment: @BooberBunz  should i remove listeners when i return to previous intent? Because it seems like 2 listeners for the same node running

Comment: Maybe.  I'm not sure since I don't have all the code to test.